# Right click goes back a page

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, mouse-click, wireless-mouse

For some strange reason, whenever I right click on my USB mouse, it goes back to the previous page that I was browsing. This can be hindering when I'm attempting to use right click to access something in the context menu. I'm using the latest version of Firefox(57.0.2) as of now, but this result even occurs in Google Chrome! For even stranger reasons, it doesn't happen with my touch pad.

Even as of now, I had to remember not to right click on "touchpad" to correct the spelling :P

Comment: Maybe "X-Mouse Button Control" was installed and configured that way? (my configuration: right click does PgDn, right button held: context menu)

Comment: I haven't heard of that until now, so I don't think I had it installed. I have no way of checking, unfortunately. Thanks for suggesting that, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This occasionally happens to me as well. I've figured out the cause (in my case), that is my mouse sometimes register a single right click as double right click.

The explanation is that right clicking on a web page opens a context menu:

[image: Context Menu]

If the mouse register right button *pressed down* as single right click, then it will open the context menu. If you happen to right click on upper half of the page, your cursor will be conveniently highlight the *Back* menu. Upon right button release, it will again register as a right click, which activates the *Back* menu.

The solution is to change your mouse, or find a program to prevent accidental double click.

Comment: Great explanation of the problem. I guess I'l need to find a new mouse again, or browse the web for a program like you suggested.

Comment: Great explanation of the problem. But what is the solution?? I've try replacing a few mice - but it happen on all of them

Comment: @GilEpshtain either all of them has the same defect, or there is something else. You can try a program that is designed to prevent accidental double click, then.